# Where exactly to insert onPause() in Android?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for this question, I'm a beginner.
My first app has been rejected due to violating the Device and Network Abuse policy.

Edit: Main reason is that Youtube video doesn't stop playing when the display is turned off...
some info here:
[Volating the Device and Network Abuse policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276810/volating-the-device-and-network-abuse-policy)

I should add

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  mWebView.onPause();
}
```

But where exactly I should insert this code?

Please help.
My Java code is here:

```
    WebView asw_view;
    ProgressBar asw_progress;
    TextView asw_loading_text;
    NotificationManager asw_notification;
    Notification asw_notification_new;

    private String asw_cam_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> asw_file_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> asw_file_path;
    private final static int asw_file_req = 1;

    private final static int loc_perm = 1;
    private final static int file_perm = 2;

    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
                    if (null == asw_file_path) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null || intent.getData() == null) {
                        if (asw_cam_message != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(asw_cam_message)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
                        } else {
                            if(ASWP_MULFILE) {
                                if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
                                    final int numSelectedFiles = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
                                    results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                                        results[i] = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            asw_file_path = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
                if (null == asw_file_message) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                asw_file_message.onReceiveValue(result);
                asw_file_message = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w("READ_PERM = ",Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Log.w("WRITE_PERM = ",Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        //Prevent the app from being started again when it is still alive in the background
        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ASWP_PBAR) {
            asw_progress = findViewById(R.id.msw_progress);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.msw_progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        asw_loading_text = findViewById(R.id.msw_loading_text);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        //Launching app rating request
        if (ASWP_RATINGS) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { get_rating(); }}, 1000 * 60); //running request after few moments
        }

        //Getting basic device information
        get_info();

        //Getting GPS location of device if given permission
        if(!check_permission(1)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, loc_perm);
        }
        get_location();

        asw_view = findViewById(R.id.msw_view);

        //Webview settings; defaults are customized for best performance
        WebSettings webSettings = asw_view.getSettings();

        if(!ASWP_OFFLINE){
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(ASWP_JSCRIPT);
        }
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(ASWP_SFORM);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(ASWP_ZOOM);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(ASWP_LOCATION);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        asw_view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription(getString(R.string.dl_downloading));
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                assert dm != null;
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dl_downloading2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            asw_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            asw_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        asw_view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        asw_view.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        asw_view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        asw_view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        asw_view.setInitialScale(1);
        asw_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Rendering the default URL
        aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);

        asw_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 16+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                    asw_file_message = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
                    if(ASWP_MULFILE) {
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    }
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.fl_chooser)), asw_file_req);
                }
            }
            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                get_file();
                if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                    if (asw_file_path != null) {
                        asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    asw_file_path = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = null;
                    if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD) {
                        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = create_image();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", asw_cam_message);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                asw_cam_message = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            } else {
                                takePictureIntent = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    if(!ASWP_ONLYCAM) {
                        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        contentSelectionIntent.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
                        if (ASWP_MULFILE) {
                            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        }
                    }
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.fl_chooser));
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, asw_file_req);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //Getting webview rendering progress
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int p) {
                if (ASWP_PBAR) {
                    asw_progress.setProgress(p);
                    if (p == 100) {
                        asw_progress.setProgress(0);
                    }
                }
            }

        // overload the geoLocations permissions prompt to always allow instantly as app permission was granted previously
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && check_permission(1))){
            // location permissions were granted previously so auto-approve
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        } else {
            // location permissions not granted so request them
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, loc_perm);
        }
    }
        });
        if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
            String path     = getIntent().getDataString();
            /*
            If you want to check or use specific directories or schemes or hosts

            Uri data        = getIntent().getData();
            String scheme   = data.getScheme();
            String host     = data.getHost();
            List<String> pr = data.getPathSegments();
            String param1   = pr.get(0);
            */
            aswm_view(path, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Coloring the "recent apps" tab header; doing it onResume, as an insurance
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDesc;
            taskDesc = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name), bm, getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            MainActivity.this.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
        }
        get_location();
    }

    //Setting activity layout visibility
    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            get_location();
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.msw_welcome).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.msw_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        //For android below API 23
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            aswm_view("file:///android_res/raw/error.html", false);
        }

        //Overriding webview URLs
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return url_actions(view, url);
        }

        //Overriding webview URLs for API 23+ [suggested by github.com/JakePou]
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return url_actions(view, request.getUrl().toString());
        }
    }

    //Random ID creation function to help get fresh cache every-time webview reloaded
    public String random_id() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }

    //Opening URLs inside webview with request
    void aswm_view(String url, Boolean tab) {
        if (tab) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
       if(url.contains("?")){ // check to see whether the url already has query parameters and handle appropriately.
        url += "&";
       } else {
            url += "?";
       }
       url += "rid="+random_id();
       asw_view.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }

    //Actions based on shouldOverrideUrlLoading
    public boolean url_actions(WebView view, String url){
        boolean a = true;
        //Show toast error if not connected to the network
        if (!ASWP_OFFLINE && !DetectConnection.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.check_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Use this in a hyperlink to redirect back to default URL :: href="refresh:android"
        } else if (url.startsWith("refresh:")) {
            aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);

            //Use this in a hyperlink to launch default phone dialer for specific number :: href="tel:+919876543210"
        } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

            //Use this to open your apps page on google play store app :: href="rate:android"
        } else if (url.startsWith("rate:")) {
            final String app_package = getPackageName(); //requesting app package name from Context or Activity object
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + app_package)));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + app_package)));
            }

            //Sharing content from your webview to external apps :: href="share:URL" and remember to place the URL you want to share after share:___
        } else if (url.startsWith("share:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, view.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, view.getTitle()+"\nVisit: "+(Uri.parse(url).toString()).replace("share:",""));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share_w_friends)));

            //Use this in a hyperlink to exit your app :: href="exit:android"
        } else if (url.startsWith("exit:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            //Opening external URLs in android default web browser
        } else if (ASWP_EXTURL && !aswm_host(url).equals(ASWV_HOST)) {
            aswm_view(url,true);
        } else {
            a = false;
        }
        return a;
    }

    //Getting host name
    public static String aswm_host(String url){
        if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        int dslash = url.indexOf("//");
        if (dslash == -1) {
            dslash = 0;
        } else {
            dslash += 2;
        }
        int end = url.indexOf('/', dslash);
        end = end >= 0 ? end : url.length();
        int port = url.indexOf(':', dslash);
        end = (port > 0 && port < end) ? port : end;
        Log.w("URL Host: ",url.substring(dslash, end));
        return url.substring(dslash, end);
    }

    //Getting device basic information
    public void get_info(){
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "DEVICE=android");
        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "DEV_API=" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    }

    //Checking permission for storage and camera for writing and uploading images
    public void get_file(){
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        //Checking for storage permission to write images for upload
        if (ASWP_FUPLOAD && ASWP_CAMUPLOAD && !check_permission(2) && !check_permission(3)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, file_perm);

        //Checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
        } else if (ASWP_FUPLOAD && !check_permission(2)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file_perm);

        //Checking for CAMERA permissions
        } else if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD && !check_permission(3)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, file_perm);
        }
    }

    //Using cookies to update user locations
    public void get_location(){
        //Checking for location permissions
        if (ASWP_LOCATION && ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && check_permission(1)) || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)) {
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            GPSTrack gps;
            gps = new GPSTrack(MainActivity.this);
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
                    cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "lat=" + latitude);
                    cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "long=" + longitude);
                    //Log.w("New Updated Location:", latitude + "," + longitude);  //enable to test dummy latitude and longitude
                } else {
                    Log.w("New Updated Location:", "NULL");
                }
            } else {
                show_notification(1, 1);
                Log.w("New Updated Location:", "FAIL");
            }
        }
    }

    //Checking if particular permission is given or not
    public boolean check_permission(int permission){
        switch(permission){
            case 1:
                return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            case 2:
                return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            case 3:
                return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        }
        return false;
    }

    //Creating image file for upload
    private File create_image() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String file_name    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String new_name     = "file_"+file_name+"_";
        File sd_directory   = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".jpg", sd_directory);
    }

    //Launching app rating dialoge [developed by github.com/hotchemi]
    public void get_rating() {
        if (DetectConnection.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            AppRate.with(this)
                .setStoreType(StoreType.GOOGLEPLAY)     //default is Google Play, other option is Amazon App Store
                .setInstallDays(SmartWebView.ASWR_DAYS)
                .setLaunchTimes(SmartWebView.ASWR_TIMES)
                .setRemindInterval(SmartWebView.ASWR_INTERVAL)
                .setTitle(R.string.rate_dialog_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.rate_dialog_message)
                .setTextLater(R.string.rate_dialog_cancel)
                .setTextNever(R.string.rate_dialog_no)
                .setTextRateNow(R.string.rate_dialog_ok)
                .monitor();
            AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);
        }
        //for more customizations, look for AppRate and DialogManager
    }

    //Creating custom notifications with IDs
    public void show_notification(int type, int id) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        asw_notification = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        if (type == 1) {
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        } else if (type == 2) {
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        } else {
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        }
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "");
        switch(type){
            case 1:
                builder.setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.loc_fail));
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.loc_fail_text));
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.loc_fail_more)));
                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{350,350,350,350,350});
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            break;

            case 2:
                builder.setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.loc_perm));
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.loc_perm_text));
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.loc_perm_more)));
                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{350, 700, 350, 700, 350});
                builder.setSound(alarmSound);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            break;
        }
        builder.setOngoing(false);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setWhen(when);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        asw_notification_new = builder.build();
        asw_notification.notify(id, asw_notification_new);
    }

    //Checking if users allowed the requested permissions or not
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode){
            case 1: {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    get_location();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Action on back key tap/click
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (asw_view.canGoBack()) {
                        asw_view.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        asw_view.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        asw_view.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Violating it for what?  There's lots of things you could be doing wrong.  You don't give us enough data to help you.  I suggest you post their description of the problem from the email.

Comment: @GabeSechan Google's violation emails are _incredibly_ vague, probably because they're all automated. That SO Q&A OP linked is probably the best way to go about fixing this.

Comment: Question edited. Problem is with YT video plaiying after display is turned off.

Comment: That's against YouTube's ToS, as described in the email. So that's why your app was removed. Only YouTube can play YouTube videos in the background and be published on the Play Store.

Comment: @TheWanderer Some are vague, some aren't.  I've seen many that were quite plain.  But they all tell us more than just "Network Abuse Policy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere you want inside your Activity class (the one you pasted in your question).

I usually try to order my lifecycle methods in the order Android executes them, so I'd put it after `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    asm_view.onResume(); //remember to add this so your WebView can resume

    //Coloring the "recent apps" tab header; doing it onResume, as an insurance
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDesc;
        taskDesc = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name), bm, getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        MainActivity.this.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
    }
    get_location();
}

@Ovveride 
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    asw_view.onPause(); //your WebView variable is asm_view, not mWebView, which is just example code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day :)

Comment: App is approved and alive, thank you! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikidiy.wikidiy

Comment: @WikidiyOrg just remember that onPause is also available in fragments, not only activities: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

onPause is a lifecycle method of Activity (and Fragments) and can be placed anywhere in the Activity class but putting your lifecycle methods in the order they are executed will help making your code more readable.