# Android app rejection: Your app doesn't comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: android-studio, google-play, android-youtube-api

I got App rejection notification from Google Play. the reason is
**Issue with your app
Your app doesn't comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy.
Issue details.We found an issue in the following area(s):
In-app experience: Please see attached screenshot**
[image]
I am using Youtube player. But I cannot understand what is the wrong. My player xml is as follows

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/yt_player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:useWebUi="true"
        app:showFullScreenButton="true">

    </com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yt_player"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your custom title and youtube title masup. remove your custom title and try again.

Comment: yes after changing webUI true in xml, my app accepted

Answer (score 1):

This is the policy that relates to your issue: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379

I suspect that your app may be violating the YouTube terms of service as another person has been having this issue here: [Violating the Device and Network Abuse policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276810/violating-the-device-and-network-abuse-policy?rq=1)